# Cannot find 'OSSignposter' in scope

Tags: swift, macos, instruments, xcode-instruments

I am new to Instruments and I want to use the new struct OSSignposter.
To use it I updated macOS to 12.0.1. My Xcode Version is 13.0.

When I try to create an instance of OSSignposter I get the Error message "Cannot find 'OSSignposter' in scope".

The small Codesnippet is:

```
import os
let signpost = OSSignposter()
```

Can someone help me to fix that issue.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the people facing the same issue, the import is:

```
import os.signpost
```